# DELETE {URL} 422 (Unprocessable Entity) (MERN Project)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I have got the following error. I have tried whatever i can to solve this issue but couldn't help myself.
Can anyone guide me on this, please?

**DELETE http://localhost:3000/deletepost/5ee38de39f82bf383c1d5a5c 422 (Unprocessable Entity)**

Codes

Client

```
const deletePost=(postid)=>{
    // 
        fetch(`/deletepost/${postid}`,{
            method:'delete',
            headers:{

                "Authorization":"Bearer "+localStorage.getItem('jwt')
            }
        }).then(res=>res.json()
        )
        .then(result=>{
            console.log(result)
            const newData = data.filter(item=>{
                return item._id !== result._id
            })
            setData(newData)
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.log(error)
        })

    }
```

Server

```
router.delete('/deletepost/:postId',requirelog,(req,res)=>{
    Post.findOne({_id:req.param.postId})
    .populate("postedBy","_id")
    .exec((error, post)=>{
        if(error || !post){

            return res.status(422).json({
                error
            })
        }
        if(post.postedBy._id.toString()===req.user._id.toString()){
            post.remove()
            .then(result=>{

                res.json(result)
            })
            .catch(err=>{
                console.log(err)
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: `req.param.postId` is probably string, does that match the type of `_id` in your documents?

Comment: What a silly mistake I had made!  the server was getting ID of undefined because of a typing error, instead of `req.param.postId` i was supposed to write `req.params.postId`